# Tridion 2013 SP1 Page URL

Tags: 2013-sp1, structuregroups, navigation

I am working on Tridion 2013 SP1, and navigation is based on Structure Groups and Pages. We have a Structure Group defined under Root and currently the page URL is displaying according to that. As per the requirement, we want the page URL at the root level for one particular structure group.

Current page url: `www.abc.com/product/index.html, www.abc.com/product/prd1/index.html`

Expected page url: `www.abc.com/index.html, www.abc.com/prd1/index.html`

We want to eliminate the Structure Group directory of the immediate Root.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using DXA's OOTB navigation or do you have a custom solution for generating the navigation?
Furthermore, are we just talking navigation here, or do you want to affect the actual URLs of the pages?

In its current form, the question is quite vague, so the answer I can give you will be as well. I am assuming this is for navigation only as you cannot override the actual URLs of pages (without having custom logic in your WebApp for resolving the modified URLs to actual pages, or by using redirects).

To adjust the navigation, look at your current implementation for generating it and customize it to your needs. To make it more generic, instead of hardcoding the SG to remove, you can use Structure Group metadata to affect the behaviour (this is standard practice).

If you provide additional data, we can probably give you more concrete pointers.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your requirement i have understood below:

1. your page index.html present under following structure group hierarchy where URL is "www.abc.com/product/prd1/index.html": root > product > prd1
2. you want to URL be as "www.abc.com/prd1/index.html".

Honestly there is no outbox functionality to achieve that.

as an workaround you do 1 of the following:

1. as Atila mentioned, you can use Structure group metadata
2. you can set up redirect rule
3. you can set up custom logic